# VBA find function can't find given value

Tags: function, vba, excel, find

I have written a program that, at one point, searches a row for a given vendor name, and then pulls that vendor's project cost from that column. The vendor name in the spreadsheet is pulled directly from a cover page, and the program reads the vendor name from that same source. This program is in 80+ separate excel files, and works beautifully in almost every single one. However, there are two or three that can't find any of the values in the given range, despite the fact that I am looking right at the value that I'm trying to search for. I tried manually using the find function in Excel, and it fails to find the string as well. What could be preventing Excel from finding these values?

```
With Worksheets("Decision Matrix Summary")
    m = 0
    For Each c In .Range("N23:N42")
        If c.Value <= 10 And c.Value > 0 Then
            m = m + 1
            vendor = c.Offset(0, -13).Value
            Worksheets("Supplier Cost Comparison").Cells(2, m + 1) = vendor
            Set cell = Worksheets("Bid Tabulation Summary").Rows("9").Find(what:=vendor, after:=Worksheets("Bid Tabulation Summary").Cells(9, 1), _
                LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart, searchorder:=xlByColumns, searchdirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, searchformat:=False)
            If Not cell Is Nothing Then
                bottomcell = cell.Offset(60000, 0).Address
                cell = Worksheets("Bid Tabulation Summary").Range(bottomcell).End(xlUp).Address
                Worksheets("Supplier Cost Comparison").Cells(3, m + 1).Value = Worksheets("Bid Tabulation Summary").Range(cell).Value
            Else
            MsgBox ("A vendor could not be found in the Bid Tabulation Summary. Please refer to the Supplier Cost Comparison tab to determine which vendor.")
            Error = "Very Yes"
            Exit Sub
            End If
        Else: End If
    Next
End With
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: I fixed it. I cleared the formatting from the cells where I want to find the values, and then re-entered the formulas. Is there a format that prevents a cell from being searched? I set the function to ignore formatting, so to my knowledge, that shouldn't have been an issue. I would appreciated any information that anyone has about that.

Comment: The most obvious explanation is that the value in the cell isn't what you think it is.  Can you provide a couple of examples?

Comment: have you checked for any rogue characters?

Comment: Try `what:=Trim(vendor)` instead of `what:=vendor` Also check if chnaging `LookIn:=xlValues` to `LookIn:=xlFormulas` makes a difference?

Comment: You are hard-coding the names of your worksheets... Perhaps the worksheet name has been modified?

Comment: Thanks for the responses! I worked through all these suggestions while troubleshooting intitially; the only exception is the Trim(vendor) addition, which didn't make a difference. Thankfully, I figured out a solution; please refer to my edit. I still don't know what was preventing the find function from working in the first place.

Comment: That shouldn't have made an issue. You already have `searchformat:=False`

Comment: That was my thought as well, but it's definitely working now, and clearing formats was the only change I made.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. I cleared the formatting from the cells where I want to find the values, and then re-entered the formulas. The find function in both Excel and VBA successfully locate the values in the search range, and return the correct location of that cell via my program.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but it was one of the things I came upon when looking for a solution to the same problem. It isn't the formats that are causing the issue. For some reason, Excel is not recognizing the contents of the cells as values. I don't even have any formulas in my range, but it won't recognize some of them as a value.

It will still find it if you change `Lookin:=xlValues` to `Lookin:=xlFormulas`, though, so as a workaround, I did the find with `xlValues` first, then if the range was still nothing, did the find with `xlFormulas`. Now it works fine.